# Powershell PnPListItem exceeds limits

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have folders deep inside lists that have well over 5K files in them that need to be split up and moved to archive
I am unable to use get-PnPFolderItem as it returns the dreaded 'The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold' error.

I should be able to use get-PnPListItem (with -pagesize) to get around this limit, but having a few issues.
As the folder is deep (6 levels) inside the root list get-PnPListItem returns the root list.

I tried the -FolderServerRelativeUrl switch, but it keeps returning 'The query.FolderServerRelativeUrl' argument is invalid

I tried creating a CAML Query to use, but that seems to be broken as it only returns the root folder for the list.

```
$SiteUrl = "https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/Maintenance"
$listname = "workshop"
$ServerRelUrl = "Maintenance/workshop/level1/level2/level3/level4/level5/level6"

Connect-PnPOnline -URL $siteUrl -credentials $cred

get-pnpFolderItem $serverRelUrl  # returns exceeded list view error

get-pnpListItem -list $listname -FolderServerRelativeUrl $ServerRelUrl   # returns 'the query.FolderServerRelativeUrl argument is invalid
# please tell me what this should be?

$query="<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><RowLimit>5000</RowLimit></View>"
get-pnpListItem -list $listname -query $query       # returns ALL files and folders under $listname, this is expected behaviour as it is paged and therefore does not exceed limit

# Workshop TK001 is part of the name of a file
$query='<view><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='FileDirRef'/><Value Type='Text'>'Workshop TK001'</Value></Contains></Where></Query></View>
get-pnpListItem -list $listname -query $query       # returns nothing

$query="<Query> <Where> <Contains> <FieldRef Name='FileDirRef' /> <Value Type='File'>'workshop/level1/level2/level3/level4/level5'</Value> </Contains> </Where> </Query> <ViewFields /> <QueryOptions />"
get-pnpListItem -list $listname -query $query       # returns the root folder of the list only

$query="<view Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query> <Where> <Contains> <FieldRef Name='FileDirRef' /> <Value Type='File'>'workshop/level1/level2/level3/level4/level5'</Value> </Contains> </Where> </Query> <ViewFields /> <QueryOptions /></view>"
get-pnpListItem -list $listname -query $query       # returns the exceeds list view error
get-pnpListItem -list $listname -query $query -PageSize 2000   # returns the exceeds list view error
get-pnpListItem -list $listname -PageSize 2000 -query $query   # returns the exceeds list view error
```

I would like to think that a CAML query would work, but it seems to be returning the root folder of the list instead of what it should be returning.

Some explanation of what I am missing, or reasons for its failure would be really appreciated.

A solution would be even better :)

I have tried the various methods listed and were expecting to have get-pnplistitem spit out a list for me to iterate through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get-PnPListItem with -Query and -PageSize will not work.

What you'll need to do is to use foreach loop with the get-pnplistitem command and pipe it to filter for FileDirRef value. As an example:

```
Get-PnPListItem -list $listname -PageSize 5000 | where-object {$_["FileDirRef"] -eq "workshop/level1/level2/level3/level4/level5"}
```

This approach will take longer to execute as you are getting all items for each folder. Another faster approach will be to get all items and store in a variable and then do the filtering locally. As an example:

```
$oItems = Get-PnPListItem -list $listname -PageSize 5000
foreach($oItem in $oItems)
{
    #Filter your data here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah, that was the only way I could find.

The time it takes though....

I ended up going with

```
$getlist=Get-PnPListItem -List $SrceFolder -PageSize 4500
$getlist_src=$getlist | ?{$_.FieldValues.FileDirRef -eq $srcF}
foreach($site in $getlist_src){
    $FlName = $site.FieldValues.FileLeafRef
    $SiteFldr=$site.FieldValues.FileDirRef
    $FlItem=$SrceFolder+"/"+$FlName
    $cntr=$DstFolder.split('/').count
    write-host "moving $($getlist_src.indexof($site)) of $($getlist_src.count) - $($Flname)"
    if($DstFolder.split('/').count -gt 1 ){
        for ($i=0;$i -le $cntr;$i++) {
            $siteFldr=$siteFldr.substring($siteFldr.indexof('/',2))
        }
    }
    $SiteFldr = $DstFolder + $SiteFldr
    move-pnpfile -SourceUrl $FlItem -TargetUrl $SiteFldr -Overwrite -AllowSchemaMismatch -AllowSmallerVersionLimitOnDestination -Force
}
```

I don't know if Microsoft have any metrics for number of access calls to the sharepoint folder, but doing it this way moves about 1000 files in 4 hours. Thats only 6K files per day. When you have 28K files to move, its not a workable solution.

So I went and tried to download a folder as a zip file. Figured I could do it that way, then upload the zip file so instead of 28K files, there would only be 1 file. It was a nice dream.

Turns out that when you have that many files in a folder there are a lot of files Microsoft screws up and puts in a report inside the zip file that there are some files it didn't copy. sorry about that :)

So just a tip, DON'T delete the sharepoint folder until after you have opened the zip file and verified its contents.

Seems if you have been pounding the sharepoint file for a day or so, you are lucky to download zipped files at more than 150K/sec. lots of errors :)

So third method time. Sync the site to my onedrive and copy through drag and drop the folders I need containing the thousands of files only my local drive, zip them up, then copy them back as a zipped file to sharepoint. Sounds easy :)

So 900 Kb made up of 28K files takes over 2 days to download at the throttled rate from sharepoint.

And it failed to copy all the files. only 26.5K files came down. Do you want to find which ones didn't come down???

Also think that the throttled issue with sharepoint after you have been pounding the site for a while is not just to an IP address, but from the site itself. Have tested these speeds and copying from onedrive sync from a few remote sites with exactly the same issue.

If ANYONE has any clues about how to rectify the issue with downloading multiple folders with over 7K files in each folder I would love to hear from you.